# How to avoid clipping after scaling custom page?

Tags: cocoa, printing, pagination, scaling

I have just implemented custom pagination by overriding the `-(BOOL)knowsPageRange:` and `-(NSRect)rectForPage:` methods.

These are printing the correct areas of my `NSView`, however, the printed
output is always scaled to 100%, whereas I require to set the scale to
something larger. Each of my custom pages are less than A4 size, but I want that each custom page will be printed to the whole A4 paper with scaling.

To do scaling I applied `CGAffineTransformScale` to the current graphics context during printing. Scaling works properly but clipping to the rect from `rectForPage` occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the view's frame to the size it would be when scaling is in effect. Then compute `rectForPage:` accordingly, with the scale taken into effect.